# Traer 1 resultado SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Resulta que tengo una consulta que me trae varios artículos, cada uno con su respectiva cantidad, hay algunos registros que viene el mismo artículo con varios pesajes, osea 2 registros del mismo artículo pero le varia la cantidad, necesito unificar esos artículos y la cantidad para que solo me traiga 1 con el total de los artículos.

¿Me podrian guiar sobre como hacerlo?

Anexo Codigo SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT YEAR(E0.FECHA) AS Anio, 
           MONTH(E0.FECHA) AS Mes, 
           DAY(E0.FECHA) AS Dia,
           CASE
               WHEN replace(E1.hydra, '', '') IS NULL
                    OR replace(E1.hydra, '', '') = ''
               THEN 'Manual'
               ELSE replace(E1.hydra, '', '')
           END AS HydraM, 
           E0.consecutivo, 
           E0.fecha, 
           E0.codtipodcto, 
           E0.codigo 'Nit', 
           E0.codbodega, 
           E3.nombre 'NomBode', 
           E1.codigo 'CodArt', 
           E2.nombre, 
           SUM(E1.cantidad) AS Cantidad
    FROM tblencfacturas E0
         INNER JOIN tblmvtofacturas E1 ON E0.consecutivo = E1.consecutivo
         INNER JOIN tblarticulos E2 ON E2.codigo = E1.codigo
         INNER JOIN tblbodegas E3 ON E3.codbodega = E1.codbodega
    --Esto cambiaria de tu codigo
    WHERE YEAR(E0.FECHA) = '2019'
          AND MONTH(E0.FECHA) = '01'
          AND DAY(E0.FECHA) = '17'
    GROUP BY YEAR(E0.FECHA), 
             MONTH(E0.FECHA), 
             DAY(E0.FECHA),
             CASE
                 WHEN replace(E1.hydra, '', '') IS NULL
                      OR replace(E1.hydra, '', '') = ''
                 THEN 'Manual'
                 ELSE replace(E1.hydra, '', '')
             END, 
             ISNULL(E1.cantidad, 0), 
             E0.consecutivo, 
             E0.fecha, 
             E0.codtipodcto, 
             E0.codigo, 
             E0.codbodega, 
             E3.nombre, 
             E1.codigo, 
             E2.nombre
) AS F0
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT YEAR(T0.D_FECHA) AS T_Anio, 
           MONTH(T0.D_FECHA) AS T_Mes, 
           DAY(T0.D_FECHA) AS T_Dia, 
           T0.D_FECHA AS T_Fecha, 
           T0.HOUR AS T_hora, 
           T0.NUME, 
           T1.CODIGO AS T_Codigo, 
           T1.NOMBRE AS T_nombre, 
           SUM(ISNULL(T0.WEIGHT, 0)) AS T_Cantidad
    FROM tbltickets T0
         INNER JOIN tblarticulos T1 ON T0.CODE = T1.CODALTERNO
    WHERE YEAR(T0.D_FECHA) = '2019'
          AND MONTH(T0.D_FECHA) = '01'
          AND DAY(T0.D_FECHA) = '17'
    GROUP BY YEAR(T0.D_FECHA), 
             MONTH(T0.D_FECHA), 
             DAY(T0.D_FECHA), 
             T0.D_FECHA, 
             T0.HOUR, 
             T0.NUME, 
             T1.CODIGO, 
             T1.NOMBRE
) AS T0 ON F0.Anio = T0.T_Anio
           AND F0.Mes = T0.T_Mes
           AND F0.Dia = T0.T_Dia
           AND F0.HydraM = T0.NUME
           AND F0.CodArt = T0.T_CODIGO;
```

Comment: Queres hacer un group by?

Comment: ya hice uno, en el cual tengo el nombre, y el codigo, pero aun asi no me los agrupa

Comment: Que quieres hacer con la cantidad? sumar? maxima? minima?. Debes orientarte en como agrupar.

Comment: quiero que cuando sean el mismo producto, con diferentes cantidades me sume las cantidades y solo me muestre 1 vez el producto ej: tengo E1 con cantidad 1.0 y E1 con cantidad 3.0, quiero que solo me diga E1 y cantidad 4.0

Comment: Eso se hace con un group by. Por favor mostranos el resultado de esta consulta para poder ayudarte

Comment: Estoy usando Crystal Reports para sacar el reporte y este es el resultado que me da, necesito que los 2 campos se unifiquen y quede solo 1 con el total de ambos http://subirimagen.me/uploads/20190128140209.PNG

Comment: A ver.. Entiendo que estás listando artículos que están en facturas y en tickets, por que no planteas en primer lugar las dos consultas con un UNION y luego toda esta como una subconsulta  con un GROUP BY?

Comment: ya logre solucionarlo, en el primer group by habia un  ISNULL con el cantidad, y este no dejaba que se unieran, lo elimine y perfecto! muchas gracias igualmente por su ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero este codigo te funcione, a mi me trae el total por articulos

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT YEAR(E0.FECHA) AS Anio, 
           MONTH(E0.FECHA) AS Mes, 
           DAY(E0.FECHA) AS Dia,
           CASE
               WHEN replace(E1.hydra, '', '') IS NULL
                    OR replace(E1.hydra, '', '') = ''
               THEN 'Manual'
               ELSE replace(E1.hydra, '', '')
           END AS HydraM, 
           E0.consecutivo, 
           E0.fecha, 
           E0.codtipodcto, 
           E0.codigo 'Nit', 
           E0.codbodega, 
           E3.nombre 'NomBode', 
           E1.codigo 'CodArt', 
           E2.nombre, 
           SUM(E1.cantidad) AS Cantidad
    FROM tblencfacturas E0
         INNER JOIN tblmvtofacturas E1 ON E0.consecutivo = E1.consecutivo
         INNER JOIN tblarticulos E2 ON E2.codigo = E1.codigo
         INNER JOIN tblbodegas E3 ON E3.codbodega = E1.codbodega
    --Esto cambiaria de tu codigo
    WHERE YEAR(E0.FECHA) = '2019'
          AND MONTH(E0.FECHA) = '01'
          AND DAY(E0.FECHA) = '17'
    GROUP BY YEAR(E0.FECHA), 
             MONTH(E0.FECHA), 
             DAY(E0.FECHA),
             CASE
                 WHEN replace(E1.hydra, '', '') IS NULL
                      OR replace(E1.hydra, '', '') = ''
                 THEN 'Manual'
                 ELSE replace(E1.hydra, '', '')
             END, 
             ISNULL(E1.cantidad, 0), 
             E0.consecutivo, 
             E0.fecha, 
             E0.codtipodcto, 
             E0.codigo, 
             E0.codbodega, 
             E3.nombre, 
             E1.codigo, 
             E2.nombre
) AS F0
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT YEAR(T0.D_FECHA) AS T_Anio, 
           MONTH(T0.D_FECHA) AS T_Mes, 
           DAY(T0.D_FECHA) AS T_Dia, 
           T0.D_FECHA AS T_Fecha, 
           T0.HOUR AS T_hora, 
           T0.NUME, 
           T1.CODIGO AS T_Codigo, 
           T1.NOMBRE AS T_nombre, 
           SUM(ISNULL(T0.WEIGHT, 0)) AS T_Cantidad
    FROM tbltickets T0
         INNER JOIN tblarticulos T1 ON T0.CODE = T1.CODALTERNO
    WHERE YEAR(T0.D_FECHA) = '2019'
          AND MONTH(T0.D_FECHA) = '01'
          AND DAY(T0.D_FECHA) = '17'
    GROUP BY YEAR(T0.D_FECHA), 
             MONTH(T0.D_FECHA), 
             DAY(T0.D_FECHA), 
             T0.D_FECHA, 
             T0.HOUR, 
             T0.NUME, 
             T1.CODIGO, 
             T1.NOMBRE
) AS T0 ON F0.Anio = T0.T_Anio
           AND F0.Mes = T0.T_Mes
           AND F0.Dia = T0.T_Dia
           AND F0.HydraM = T0.NUME
           AND F0.CodArt = T0.T_CODIGO;
```

Answer (score 1):

Cambia el primer `SELECT` donde tienes `Select *` por cada campo, suma los campos que necesitas y agrupas al final de la consulta por los campos no calculados, mas o menos así:

```
SELECT anio, mes dia, SUM (campo) FROM ( SELECT.....) as F0 FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT .....)
GROUP BY anio, mes dia
```

Con esto obtienes la suma de ambas consultas y agrupas por su `año`, `mes` y `día`.